# MS Excel - Separate texts by delimiter into specific columns

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, spreadsheet

In MS Excel, I need to separate text by comma, extract three things from right and put them in three different columns i.e. city, State and Country.

Problem: In the original text which is the full address, I sometimes get only the country or only the state. Also, the length of the full address is varied.

[image: Here's a screenshot of what I intend to do]

and Here's the actual [spreadsheet](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ad-LkbI_l60sReYhPoonUYxc7vOuAMrN/view?usp=sharing).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First enter the following three user defined functions in a standard module:

```
Public Function LastWord(s As String) As String
    Dim arr
    s = ", , , , , " & s
    arr = Split(s, ", ")
    LastWord = arr(UBound(arr))
End Function

Public Function NLastWord(s As String) As String
    Dim arr
    s = ", , , , , " & s
    arr = Split(s, ", ")
    NLastWord = arr(UBound(arr) - 1)
End Function

Public Function NNLastWord(s As String) As String
    Dim arr
    s = ", , , , , " & s
    arr = Split(s, ", ")
    NNLastWord = arr(UBound(arr) - 2)
End Function
```

then in **E1** enter:

```
=lastword(A1)
```

and copy downward.  In **D1** enter:

```
=NLastWord(A1)
```

and copy downwards.  In **C1** enter:

```
=NNLastWord(A1)
```

and copy downwards:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Assume data housed in `A1:A6` as per screenshot

In `C1`, formula copied across and down :

```
=IFERROR(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(","&$A1,",",REPT(" ",399)),(LEN($A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(($A1),",",""))+COLUMN(A1)-2)*399,399)),"")
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have Excel 2013+ with the `FILTERXML` function, you can use:

```
=IFERROR(FILTERXML("<t><s>" & SUBSTITUTE($A1,",","</s><s>") & "</s></t>","//s[last()-3+" & COLUMNS($A:A) & "]"),"")
```

Fill across and down.

- Create an XML with each comma-separated string being a *node*
- Extract the last 3 nodes, returning a `""` if it is not existent.

[image]